# Pattern matching in Lua to snip words at starting and end of text chunk

Tags: arrays, string, lua, pattern-matching

My objective is to find a pattern similar to the below,

```
  space channel space
```

which I would like to snip off in text chunk (pages') starting and ending.

I wrote the below code in Lua. My below code will work only of a 1 letter pattern.

**How should I make it work for any word with such *space word space* pattern which should snip off an array index value present in
    starting and ending of a page?**

```html
singleChar = ' and third party cookies (such as the DoubleClick cookie) together to (a) inform, optimize and serve ads based on a users past visits to '

totaLen = string.len(singleChar)

totalen = -totaLen

print('actual singleChar - '..singleChar)

singleCharChecking = string.sub(singleChar,-2,-1)

print ('singleCharChecking - '..singleCharChecking)

checkPattern = string.gmatch(singleCharChecking,"%s%a")

for word in checkPattern do
 checkPatternLen = string.len(word)
 print(checkPatternLen)
 if (checkPatternLen == 2) then
  singleChar = string.sub(singleChar,totalen,-2)
  print('single char - '..singleChar)
 end
end
```

**Input:** singleChar = ' and third party cookies (such as the DoubleClick cookie) together to (a) inform, optimize and serve ads based on a users past visits to '

**Expected output:**
third party cookies (such as the DoubleClick cookie) together to (a) inform, optimize and serve ads based on a users past visits

Comment: Could you please provide a sample string and expected output?

Comment: Wiktor - please find as updated above

Comment: So, you want to remove the first and last non-whitespace chunks from a string? Try `string.gsub(your_string_here, "^%s*%S+%s*(.*%S)%s+%S+%s*$", "%1")` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/FY1o21)).

Comment: Thank you its working in a tiny code snippet. You can post this as an answer. (However I am still facing an issue which is not connected to your solution. Your solution is working good.)

Comment: Could you teach me how you got that pattern and limiting (%1)

Comment: The `(...)` create a *capture* that you may later refer to with a backreference that has `%`+`n` syntax where `n` is the group ID. The IDs start with `1`, from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scenario 1: Either start or end pattern should be stripped off

Or, you may split this into 2 gsub operations to make it a bit less complicated:

```
local s = string.gsub(" and some text channel ", "^%s+%S+%s+", "")
s = s:gsub("%s+%S+%s*$", "")
```

The first line will remove the initial 1+ whitespace, 1+ non-whitespaces, 1+ whitespaces, and the second line will stip the same pattern at the end of the string.

## Scenario 2: If the start and end patterns must both exit

Since you want to remove the first and last non-whitespace chunks from a string you may use

```
string.gsub(" and some text channel ", "^%s+%S+%s+(.*%S)%s+%S+%s+$", "%1")
```

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/S7fJGR)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `%s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `%S+`  - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `%s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*%S)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars up greedily to the last non-whitespace char followed with
- `%s+%S+%s*$` - 1+ whitespaces (`%s+`), 1+ non-whitespaces (`%S+`) and 0+ whitespaces (`%s*`) at the end of the string (`$`).

The `%1` in the replacement part re-inserts Group 1 contents back into the result.

Comment: Wiktor - This pattern is not working correctly. `string.gsub(your_string_here, "^%s*%S+%s*(.*%S)%s+%S+%s*$", "%1")` There is a correction needed in the solution given. I have accepted it without unit testing something. which is no matter if there is a space or not in the string **` and some text channel `**, it's being removed. **How to fix this** –

Comment: But https://ideone.com/DxYI5S is exactly showing `some text` result for `" and some text channel "` input - isn't that what you want?

Comment: Remove the space which is in front of  ** and ...** and execute. There will be same output (which supposed to be not, as per mentioned pattern.)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. Your string `" and some text channel "` does not contain `**`, nor `...`. Both snippets yield `some text`

Comment: Please replace `" and some text channel "` with `"and some text channel "`and check the output. It will yield the same. Which shouldn't be because the pattern written for **space word space**.

Comment: Input-> `" and some text channel "` expected output is -> `"some text"`. Input-> `"and some text channel "` expected output is -> `"and some text"`

Comment: I thought you need a solution that is more generic. I think `"^%s+%S+%s+(.*%S)%s+%S+%s+$"` will work as you need then.

Comment: This isn't snipping off but displaying the word `channel` too.. Input-> `"and some text channel "` expected output is -> `"and some text"`

Comment: Ok, that means you need the 2 pass approach I suggested before as an alternative.  Reposted as the first solution.

Comment: What is the expression for multiple white space? (Where from you studied all these expressions)

Comment: Multiple whitespace? No idea what you mean. See [Quick-Start: Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

Comment: This `%s+` captures a space. What is the expression to capture if there are a long tab, long space.

Comment: Could you please share the exact input string with those chars?

Comment: I am processing a 97KB of notepad which is containing a string data. I am using an API (which I cannot share here). This API is capable of accommodating these string from notepad and allocate it into Lua Pages. When it does, in few pages at right bottom corner the last word is truncated into two halves. where the first half is on right bottom corner of first page and second half is on left top corner on second page. I am trying to eliminate this by either move it to next page or the other way.

Comment: I cannot help since I do not have the data. Only if you share the *sample string data* can I (or anyone else) help. I am not interested in what API you are using.

Comment: I am trying to process text file hosted online and display in a device page by page. Practically I cannot stage the error or issue since it's on a device locally in my environment. As my above comment it is the issue of a word truncating into 2halves each half on a page. A page's entire text is a from an `array[index]` value. So each page's text is a string data of an `array[index]`. The issue is truncated word's 1st half is on one page of `array[1]` and 2nd half of the word is on second page of `array[2]`.

Comment: This is not helping me understand what the *long tab, long space* are. What are their Unicode code points, what do they look like?

Comment: It would be the human readable form of `%s` but it would be multiple times `%s+%s+%s+`.

Comment: can this replace a `,` with a # in a string?`s = string.gsub(" and some, text channel ", "^*(.,*%S)#*$", "%1")print(s)`

Comment: `s = string.gsub(" and some, text channel ", ",",  "#")`